# Need help horizontally aligning and distributing text

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to build out my simple landing page:

[image]

and I am struggling to do the following:

**Elegantly rotate the group of links on the right of my design in a way that equally distributes them based on the viewport’s height.**

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);   
}

footer ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}

footer ul li {
    display: block;
    flex: 0 1 auto; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

This approach does rotate the links, but I noticed I then have to apply negative margin to my footer to see it on the page, and it does not equally distribute the links in a way that fits on the screen.

Also, based on my design, do you think using a fixed position for both the group of links and my name to the left makes sense? I’d like to maintain consistent padding to frame the page,

Thank you for any help, and let me know if I can clarify further.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? I used `flexbox` and `text-orientation`

```css
#sidebar{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: teal;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

#sidebar > div{
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div>
    opt 1
  </div>
  <div>
    opt 2
  </div>
  <div>
    opt 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Laif's `text-orientation`.

This does not require fixed positions for any of the elements.
The only issue is your name does not match up with the first link on the right sidebar. I'm not sure how to achieve this (without js) as the content is dynamic.

```css
body,
html {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #00b49e;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.left-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.left-container>div {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 900;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.center-container {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.right-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.right-container>div {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 12px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left-container">
      <div>
        Sean Thompson
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="center-container">
      <p>
        A Designer at Twitter, in Boulder, Colorado. Inspired by minimalism, happiest in the wilderness.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <div class="right-container">
    <div>
      Twitter
    </div>
    <div>
      Resume
    </div>
    <div>
      Dribble
    </div>
    <div>
      Contact
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you both! So you cannot bake in padding that applies to both the name and group of links that is the same based on this approach?

Comment: Actually with an extra container element it was an easy fix. Please see the updated code.